# CV - Move country below city, region and hide heading if missing data

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

On the CV please move the country below the city, region.
Also if a section is missing text, for instance, someone does not enter their **About Me** information the heading should be invisible.  It doesn't look good on a printed or exported CV when you have a heading with no data within it.

This should apply for any heading that contains no data.

[image]

Comment: You've taken great care to blank out fields in your screenshot, but you do know that information is all publically available with one or two clicks from your profile, right? I mean, your main Stack Overflow profile has a link directly to your CV...

Comment: cody i know...i just have a stange habit of doing it...it doesnt take long to blank it out using snag it.

Comment: So, it would be better to edit the HTML for generic values, like John Doe, then taking a screenshot. The hidden marks makes it confusing.